# NAND Flash vs NAND EEPROM

Tags: nand, nand-flash

I'm not clear how (if) NAND EEPROM (made by Toshiba) is different compared to regular NAND Flash memories (except is cheaper).

We want to use with SAM9G device that is support NAND devices such as [MT29F2G08AAD](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Micron%20Technology%20Inc%20PDFs/MT29F2G(08,16)AAD,ABD.pdf).

The NAND EEPROM we found is [TC58NVG1S3HTAI0](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=14852&prodName=TC58NVG1S3HTAI0).

Now both share the same interface, package, same voltage and timing is quite the same. However, command list is partially the same so we don't know if it is compatible.

Anyone has used such NAND EEPROMs and can give some hints?
Thanks.

Comment: The term "NAND EEPROM" is misleading. Although flash is a kind of EEPROM, when we say "EEPROM", we usually refer to something that is byte-erasable. This is not the case of the TC58NVG1S3HTAI0, which is actually a regular NAND flash memory.

Comment: The biggest problem may be whether the SAM9G can boot from the Toshiba flash. Perhaps check with Atmel?

Comment: I already received a partial answer from Atmel and they said "don't know". They recommend me to replace part on EVK and see if works :)

Comment: @dim, indeed this is very confusing. It's just what we call a "Flash" (paginated) I really don't know why Toshiba mention Flash E2PROM all over their datasheets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The headline differences appear to be:

- Micron device is "Open NAND Flash Interface (ONFI) 1.0-compliant" while the Toshiba isn't.
- Different page sizes: Micron "x8: 2,112 bytes (2,048 + 64 bytes)" vs Toshiba (2048 + 128). The extra bits are for user-defined tagging and error recovery.

Comment: I suspected ONFI too :) My mistake, I put a link with a bigger one (Toshiba) but there are parts exactly the same.